# render_to_string returns empty string when called from controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am using rails 5.1, I have a controller, when I try to render to a string I am getting an empty string

```
def pdf_string
    path = Rails.root.join("/app/views/menu/recipe_card.pdf.erb").to_s;

   render_to_string(
      :file => path,
      locals: get_pdf_locals
    )
end
```

But if I do

```
ActionController::Base.new.render_to_string(
  :file => path,
  locals: get_pdf_locals
)
```

I am getting the view rendered. The problem is that using `ActionController::Base.new` inside my controller seems kinda odd, and the view is not having access to helper methods. Any idea why the `render_to_string` of my controller is returning emtpy string while the `ActionController::Base.new.render_to_string` is rendering correctly?

Comment: That is most certainly very odd. Did you try using `pry-byebug` to set a breakpoint and step into the method to see whether it maybe was overriden somewhere?

Comment: Can you please share your controller class definition and maybe the rest of your controller?

Comment: where's that `pdf_string` method defined? in the controler or in a helper file? it looks like you are defining it inside a helper file, which gets included in the view which does not have a render_to_string method, you can define it on the controller and add a `helper_method :pdf_string` line after it so that's used in the right context

Comment: I founded out the issue, will post the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was that my controller was extending `ActionController::API` instead of `ActionController::Base`, unfortunately the `render_to_string` was returning empty string, it would be easier to debug if it was failing hard.